# Error while trying to print HTML tags within scriplets in JSP

Tags: jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee, scriptlet

I am trying to print a variable (forwarded from a java servlet) in a jsp.
To do so I'm using the following

```
<jsp:scriptlet>
    jrservlet.Client user = (jrservlet.Client)request.getAttribute("user");
    out.println(user.toString());
</jsp:scriptlet>
```

The piece of code actually works fine, so far so good.

The issue arises when I try to format the output; like so

```
<jsp:scriptlet>
    jrservlet.Client user = (jrservlet.Client)request.getAttribute("user");
    out.println("<h1>" + user.toString() + "</h1>");
 </jsp:scriptlet>
```

The error reads

> "String literal is not properly closed by a double-quote"

and the first double quotes are underlined.

Which I find odd because from my understanding within the `<jsp:scriptlet>` I should be able to enter java code. To me the html tag`"<h1>"` should be processed as a String.

Why is it that I’m having *"what seems to me is a xml"* error?
What am I missing, could someone be kind enough to point it out?

To bypass the issue tried putting the html tag on the outside as in the following example.

```
</h1>
    <jsp:scriptlet>
        jrservlet.Client user = (jrservlet.Client)request.getAttribute("user");
        out.println(user.toString());
     </jsp:scriptlet>
<h1>
```

In the browser (Google Chrome 53 and Firefox 45) the source code seems all right, however, the typeface does not change at all; it looks nowhere close to what the `<h1>` tag should produce.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport"/>
        <title>Home</title>
        <link href="/TP1MiniProjetBanque/styles/login/css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header> some header <header/>
        <h1>6 J. Remy jremy@kepler-42.milkyway kepler Kepler-42</h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Edit : Start**
I tried adding the HTML tag directly in the String (from within the Servlet), and forwarded the whole thing to the JSP where it will then be printed.

```
request.setAttribute("userName", "<h1>" + user.getSurname() + " " + user.getName() + "</h1>");
```

That got rid of the aforementioned error in the JSP but in the browser the typeface still does not change.

These are strange behaviours; I'm clueless.
**Edit : End**

I’m using java 8 and tomcat 7.

Comment: I may be ignorant but I would just navigate around the problem and do <h1><jsp:expression>user.toString()</jsp:expression></h1>

Comment: Thanks for your responding. I'll give it a try.